# Is there a way to customize mobile keyboard in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am using a TextField Widjet and inside it i can use  keyboardType.

```
TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                controller: usernameController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hoverColor: Colors.red,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))),
                  hintText: 'Username',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
```

While using keyboardType: TextInputType.number it also shows comma,dots,(,.-). Is there a way to setup my keyboard for a particular textfield to show only numbers like when we put pin of mobile it shows only numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
TextField(
            keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
             decimal: false,
             signed: false,
            ),
            inputFormatters: [
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
            ],
            controller: usernameController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hoverColor: Colors.red,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))),
              hintText: 'Username',
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
```

Comment: It disables the input from decimal and commas but it still shows.Isn't there any way to also hide those buttons as if user cant input from those button showing it to user is not good right?